# ReactJS & ECMAScript 6 - working with Refs & Slider

Tags: reactjs

**I have 2 components: app & slider, with this relevant code:**

**1. Slider:**

```
 'use strict';
 var React = require('react');

 class Slider extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
       super(props)
   }

   render(){
       return(
           <div>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="255" ref="colors" 
                   onChange={this.props.update} />
           </div>
      )
   }
}

 module.exports = Slider;
```

**2. App:**

```
 ...
 class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          red: 0,
          green: 0,
          blue: 0
      }
  }
  updateColors(){
      this.setState ({
        red:this.refs.red.refs.colors.getDOMNode().value,
        green:this.refs.green.refs.colors.getDOMNode().value,
        blue:this.refs.blue.refs.colors.getDOMNode().value
    })
}

 render() {
    return (
            <div>
                <Slider ref="red" update={this.updateColors.bind(this)} />
                <label>Red: {this.state.red}</label>
                <Slider ref="green" update={this.updateColors.bind(this)} />
                <label>Green: {this.state.green}</label>
                <Slider ref="blue" update={this.updateColors.bind(this)} />
                <label>Blue: {this.state.blue}</label>
            </div>
      )
       .....
 };
```

[image]

**Problem:**

After page load, should I change the range of any color, the other colors change as well. Afterwards (not a new page load), the colors change respectively to whichever one was moved.

What is causing **ALL the colors** to change after initial page load, when only one color was moved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you aren't giving the slider input a value. I have modified both files to get this to work.

**Slider**

```
 'use strict';
 var React = require('react');

 class Slider extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
       super(props)
   }

   render(){
       return(
           <div>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="255" ref="colors" 
                   value={this.props.value}
                   onChange={this.props.update} />
           </div>
      )
   }
}

module.exports = Slider;
```

**App**

```
 ...
 class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          red: 0,
          green: 0,
          blue: 0
      }
  }
  updateColors(){
      this.setState ({
        red:this.refs.red.refs.colors.getDOMNode().value,
        green:this.refs.green.refs.colors.getDOMNode().value,
        blue:this.refs.blue.refs.colors.getDOMNode().value
    })
}

 render() {
    return (
            <div>
                <Slider ref="red" value={this.state.red} update={this.updateColors.bind(this)} />
                <label>Red: {this.state.red}</label>
                <Slider ref="green" value={this.state.green} update={this.updateColors.bind(this)} />
                <label>Green: {this.state.green}</label>
                <Slider ref="blue" value={this.state.blue} update={this.updateColors.bind(this)} />
                <label>Blue: {this.state.blue}</label>
            </div>
       );
    }
       .....
 };
```